# What exactly are scalar values in Fortran, and how can I convert from and to them

Tags: fortran

Some context. I have this piece of code :

```
function areeq(array1,array2) result(eq)
real :: array1(1:100,1:100), array2(1:100,1:100)
logical :: eq
integer :: x,y,f
do x=1,100
  do y = 1,100
    print *,array1(x:x,y:y)
    print *,array2(x:x,y:y)
    if(.not.(array1(x:x,y:y) == array2(x:x,y:y))) then
      eq = .false.
      return
    end if

    read *,f
  end do
end do
eq = .true.
return
end function
```

However, when I try to run it, it throws this error message:

```
if(.not.(array1(x:x,y:y) == array2(x:x,y:y))) then
       1
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression
```

This is the second time that I've encountered trouble with something needing to be Scalar, and though I managed to hack together a makeshift work around for the last time, I really ought to, and need to, be able to handle them properly.

So, TL;DR: What is wrong with this piece of code, and what should I do in situations like this more generally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

```
integer n
real x(5)
```

then, given appropriate definition of `n`

```
x(n)
```

is an array element of `x`, and

```
x(n:n)
```

is an array section of `x`.

The array element is a scalar whereas the array section is itself an array *of size 1*.

As Steve Lionel says, in the case of the question,

```
array1(x:x,y:y) == array2(x:x,y:y)
```

is an array-valued expression (albeit again of size 1) which can be reduced to a scalar expression with `ALL`.  However

```
array1(x,y) == array2(x,y)
```

is a scalar expression, with both operands scalar array elements.

---

In the reference `x(n)` we have an array element for scalar `n`.  With `n` an array we would instead have an array being a vector subscript of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong is, as the compiler complains, your expression has an array result, with one element for each comparison. What you want is to wrap the expression in ALL(). For example:

```
if(.not.(all(array1(x:x,y:y) == array2(x:x,y:y)))) then
```

Comment: Why not simply remove the array section notation?  `if (.not.(array1(x,y) == array2(x,y)))`

Comment: You could also change to " if ( array1(x,y) /= array2(x,y) ) then" ... However as array1 and array2 are defined as real, there needs to be some understanding of how different two real numbers are, ie what small difference would be tolerated

Comment: Neither of those suggestions help, as the IF expression is still an array. It has to be reduced to a scalar, which is what ALL does.

Comment: @SteveLionel, How is `array1(x,y) == array2(x,y)` an array expression? `array1(x,y)` is an element of array `array1`.  `array2(x,y)` is an element of `array2`.  An array element is scalar.

Comment: @SteveLionel, I made 2 suggestions, both of which have not been followed up. One was to simplify the if logic and the other to highlight the problem for comparison of 2 real values. While they may not address the OP question, they do address the suitability of the code written, highlighting significant problems with the coding approach.